# subdivision surface modifier question

Tags: subdivision-surface

noob here.
I come from maya, it's been just a couple of days since I started using blender 2.8
Now I was practicing hard surface modeling, really basic things, and I ran into the issue you can see in the picture: basically when I apply the subdivision surface modifier to my mesh there is an edgeloop that does not change its curvature at all, the vertex numbers increases but that is it. Anybody knows if that is how the modifier works (why would it though?) or if maybe I did not merge edgeloops properly or something?

[image: subdivided vs unsubdivided]

Comment: The only things that come to mind.. have you creased or beveled the radials of the hemisphere somewhere along the way?  (Disable any bevel modifier.. Try unchecking 'Use Crease' in the Subdiv modifier.. and check for doubled vertices with Alt-M > by proximity)....

Comment: It's certainly not meant to behave that way.  I would first check that there are no double vertices around that edge that doesn't curve properly.  If all the vertices are properly merged and it still does that, try deleting the modifier, save the scene, close down Blender, then open it again and open the scene.

Comment: You should also make sure that all face normals points outwards

Comment: Thanx everybody, it probably was a combination of all of the things you suggested. I redid the whole thing checked and flipped the normals of the hemisphere, and now it worked. Have a nice day :)